# How to perform a batch update using Codeigniter arrays?

Tags: codeigniter

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I perform a batch update using arrays in CodeIgniter
Here's my sample code:

```
 public function updateItemInfo(){

        $id = $this->input->post('idx'); //array of id
        $desc = $this->input->post('itemdesc'); //array of item name
        $qty = $this->input->post('qty'); //array or qty
        $price = $this->input->post('price'); //array of price
        $code = $this->input->post('codes'); // not array

        for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){

            $total[] = $price[$x] * $qty[$x];

            $updateArray = array(
                'item_desc' => $desc[$x],
                'item_qty' => $qty[$x],
                'price' => $price[$x],
                'total' => $total
            );
            $this->db->where('poid',$id[$x]);
            $this->db->update('po_order_details',$updateArray); //Could not update I don't know why

        }

        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($updateArray);


        $sumoftotal = array_sum($total);

        $vat_amt = $sumoftotal / 1.12;
        $vat_input = $vat_amt * 0.12;
        $total_all = $vat_amt + $vat_input;

        $updateTotal = array(
            'vatable_input' => $vat_amt,
            'vatable_amount' => $vat_input,
            'total_amount_due' => $total_all
        );

        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($updateTotal);

        //exit;

        $this->db->where('order_code',$code);
        $this->db->update('po_order_total',$updateTotal); //Here also couldn't update

    }
```

That's my code And I can't figured it out where's my error. Ia also checked my array values and there's no error in my array. My problem is I can't update my table using batch update.

Comment: Write `echo $this->db->last_query();die;` after this line : `$this->db->update('po_order_details',$updateArray); //Could not update I don't know why` to see what query is generated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try to see `update_batch` option here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

CodeIgniter 3.x: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch

You can create an `array` with all your option and then send it to the `batch_update` function.

```
$id = $this->input->post('idx'); //array of id
$desc = $this->input->post('itemdesc'); //array of item name
$qty = $this->input->post('qty'); //array or qty
$price = $this->input->post('price'); //array of price
$code = $this->input->post('codes'); // not array

$updateArray = array();

for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){

    $total[] = $price[$x] * $qty[$x];
    $updateArray[] = array(
        'poid'=>$id[$x],
        'item_desc' => $desc[$x],
        'item_qty' => $qty[$x],
        'price' => $price[$x],
        'total' => $total
    );
}      
$this->db->update_batch('po_order_details',$updateArray, 'poid');
```

Comment: is the  $this->db->update_batch('po_order_details',$updateArray, 'poid');  inside my for loop?

Comment: No sorry, it's after the for()

Comment: What if I want to have more than one field as a 'where' condition? like in additional to 'poid' also the result must match 'price'? 
*update x set f1 = d1 where f1 = cond1, f2 = cond2?

Comment: @Joraid I think in that case you should the standard update function so you can set multiple where

Comment: thanks, was hoping that update_batch could compare more than one field

Comment: This is the solution I'm looking for. I assume the code is in model file?

Comment: In the example the user required it in the controller but yes, you should use it in your model

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi thanks for your time, how about if item_qty update by current value + $qty[$x], if you don't mind here is my code http://pastebin.com/gNhkqFPB