# Updating multiple rows in one form submission Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Searched, Googled already couldn't found one with same case,

Basically i have a set of multiple categories in one form, i want to update Number of questions in each category on one form submit. 
Following is the form:
[image]

Number of categories can be dynamic, each **Question TextBox** contains its name = "question" merged with **category ID** and make it as "question12 , question13" etc.

I know about update_batch() , but how do i get values and put them in array as they can be of unknown number.

How do i update all categories at once in **CodeIgniter**

Comment: Just check the accepted answer and You can pass your array like that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465604/how-to-perform-a-batch-update-using-codeigniter-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this using foreach in Controller

```
foreach ($sample_settings as $sample) {
        $array['category_id'] = $sample['category_id'];
        $array['no_of_questions'] = $this->input->post('question'.$sample['category_id']);
        $batch_array[] = $array;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$post = $this->input->post();
foreach($post as $key=>$value){
    if(strpos($key, "question") == 0){

        $category_id = substr($key, 8);

        //Use $category_id and $value in this loop to build update statement

    }
}
```