# how to update multiple data with where condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want update multiple data's from array with where condition (2 post value)

```
$markid=50008; (Post Item)
$ass='Att1';(Post Item)

$data=array( 'regno'=>$regno,'assmark'=>$assmark);

$query="update pre_marks set $ass=$assmark where regno=$regno and markid=$markid" ;
$this->db->query($query);
```

My output should be

```
Array
(
    [regno] => 210417103001
    [Att1] => 58
)
Array
(
    [regno] => 210417103002
    [Att1] => 23
)
Array
(
    [regno] => 210417103003
    [Att1] => 20
)
Array
(
    [regno] => 210417103004
    [Att1] => 45
)
Array
(
    [regno] => 210417103005
    [Att1] => 25
)
Array
(
    [regno] => 210417103006
    [Att1] => 0
)
```

This worked as well. But error comes

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where regno= and markid=50009' at line 1
>
> update pre_marks set Att1= where regno= and markid=50009
>
> Filename:
>   ***C:/xampp/htdocs/Admin-Panel/system/database/DB_driver.php***
>
> Line Number: 691

How to solve this?

```
$markid = $this->input->post('markid');
$ass = $this->input->post('sel_ass1');                 
for($i=12;$i<=$i+6;$i++) {       
    $regno= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue();
    $assmark= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$i)->getValue();

    $data=array('regno'=>$regno,$ass=>$assmark);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';

    $this->db->where(['regno' => $regno,'markid' => $markid]);
    $this->db->update('pre_marks',[$ass => $assmark]);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the db query . you need to use quotes

Comment: is `$ass` variable dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check variables before using them in query!

```
if(!empty($markid) && !empty($ass)) {
  if(!empty($assmark) && !empty($regno)) {
    $this->db->set($ass, $assmark)
      ->where("regno", $regno)
      ->where("markid", $markid)
      ->update("pre_marks");
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {
      echo TRUE;
    }
    else {
      echo FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i wrote a coding in model its working. but its takes log time . one error came  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: @kvr, You want to update several items, right? Use `bulk update`. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465604/how-to-perform-a-batch-update-using-codeigniter-arrays

Comment: @kvr, just remove return operator from if clause: `if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {
      echo TRUE;
    }`