# Arrray to String conversion error when perform batch update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in Codeigniter.. I try to do the batch update on my code but it return an error **"Array to string conversion** and error like this :

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
> UPDATE `absensi` SET `keterangan` = Array, `ket` = Array WHERE `id_siswa` = '1'

Below is the code on Controller :

```
$input = $this->input->post();
$id_mapel = $input['id_mapel'];
$id_kelas = $input['id_kelas'];
$index = 0;
foreach ($input['id_siswa'] as $key => $val) {
  $data = [
    'id_siswa' => $input['id_siswa'][$key],
    'id_mapel' => $input['id_mapel'],
    'id_kelas' => $input['id_kelas'],
    'time_in' => time(),
    'tanggal' => date("d"),
    'bulan' => date("m"),
    'tahun' => date("Y"),
    'keterangan' => $input['keterangan'][$key],
    'ket' => $input['ket'][$key]
  ];
  $this->guru_m->ubahAbsen($data);
}
redirect('gr/absensi');
```

}

On model :

```
public function ubahAbsen($data)
{
 foreach($this->input->post('id_siswa') as $key => $value)
{
    $data = array(
        'keterangan'     => $this->input->post('keterangan'),
        'ket'       => $this->input->post('ket')
    );
    $this->db->where('id_siswa', $value);
    $this->db->update('absensi', $data);
  }
}
```

Can you tell me the correct code? I'm really dizzy to fix this error...

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465604/how-to-perform-a-batch-update-using-codeigniter-arrays

Comment: no, it's different... the case is not batch_update

Comment: can you print $this->input->post() ? what is the content of the variable ?

Comment: In your first piece of code you build up `$data` and pass it into the method `ubahAbsen()`, you then ignore this value and rebuild `$data` again.

Comment: so what should I do Nigel? can you write the complete code in the answer section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your model to this

```
public function ubahAbsen($data)
{
  $dataUpdate = array(
    'keterangan' => $data['keterangan'],
    'ket' => $data['ket']
  );
  $this->db->where('id_siswa', $data['id_siswa']);
  $this->db->update('absensi', $dataUpdate);
}
```

because variable `$data` contains single data siswa